# Why can't I access variables from another file?

Tags: javascript, webpack-encore

In my project, I use WebPackEncore to manage my libraries.

in a file I regroup all the keys needed to access API, it's called **keys.js**:

```js
const keys = {
    //> Algolia/places API
    ALGOLIA_PLACE_APP_ID: "appKey",
    ALGOLIA_PLACE_API_ID: "APIkey",
    //###< Algolia/places API

    //> MapBox API
    MAPBOX_TOKEN: "mapBoxToken",
    //< MapBox API
}
```

in my **app.js** file I try to use theses keys:

```
import keys from './keys';

//do stuff
```

If I try to use a `console.log(keys)` in my **app.js** file I get a `{}` which make it completely useless.

Is it a normal behavior and I miss a scope problem ? Is it a bad way to insert keys (I try to reproduce the behavior of my **.env** file) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not exporting the variable from `keys.js`. Try like this..

```
export default keys = {
    //> Algolia/places API
    ALGOLIA_PLACE_APP_ID: "appKey",
    ALGOLIA_PLACE_API_ID: "APIkey",
    //###< Algolia/places API

    //> MapBox API
    MAPBOX_TOKEN: "mapBoxToken",
    //< MapBox API
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer of Kelly Copley is alright but that's only if you want to export `keys` by default. If you wished to export `keys` in a modular way, try it like this:

```js
export const keys = {
    //> Algolia/places API
    ALGOLIA_PLACE_APP_ID: "appKey",
    ALGOLIA_PLACE_API_ID: "APIkey",
    //###< Algolia/places API

    //> MapBox API
    MAPBOX_TOKEN: "mapBoxToken",
    //< MapBox API
}
```

Then you import it like this:

```
import { keys } from './keys';
```

Comment: as there is just one `keys` in this file the [@Kelly copley](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60642803/6734243) answer works perfectly